# Convert GetDate() into bigint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, getdate

I am using MS SQL Server 2012

How do I convert `GetDate()` into `bigint`?

I am trying to get records for past 24 hours, and the only column that I have are `bigint` (not `datetime`)

```
select GetDate()
<Want to convert GetDate() here>

select DATEADD(SECOND, TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') 
as Date_and_Time from [dbo].[V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG] 
where EVENT_SOURCE = 'sylink'and EVENT_DESC like '%Downloaded%'
<Want to say if record is within 24 hours of the converted GetDate()>
```

ADDITION

And if I execute

```
select DATEADD(SECOND, TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') 
as Date_and_Time from [dbo].[V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG]
```

I get

```
Date_and_Time
2014-06-08 05:24:22.000
2014-06-08 05:34:19.000
2014-06-08 05:57:43.000
2014-06-08 05:57:43.000
2014-06-08 17:35:59.000
```

Comment: Stop using wrong, inappropriate datatypes! If it's a date - store it as `DATE` (if you don't need time) or `DATETIME2(n)` (if you need time) - don't hack it into a `bigint`......

Comment: What does your data actually look like?  Is it possible a Julian date?

Comment: @Andrew Date_and_Time looks like 2014-06-08 05:24:22.000

Comment: @marc_s - If I don't hack it into a bigint, how else will I compare whether Date_and_Time is within 24 hours. Because Date_and_Time is from TIME_STAMP, the actual column which is a bigint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your table contains epoch dates, which is number of seconds since 1970-01-01. It's easy to convert a DateTime to epoch like this:

```
DECLARE @EpochDate bigint
SET @EpochDate = DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', GETDATE())
PRINT @EpochDate
```

However i agree with marc_s that it's bad practice to convert dates to something else, but in many cases you have to, if for example the data is provided by a 3rd party.

I believe your query would end up looking something like this:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(SECOND, TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') as Date_and_Time 
FROM
    [dbo].[V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG] 
WHERE
    EVENT_SOURCE = 'sylink'
    and EVENT_DESC LIKE '%Downloaded%'
    and TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) * CAST(1000 as bigint)
```

Comment: for some reason it is still not working. I understand DATEADD to be the current date minus 1, i.e. yesterday's date and time. And I understand DATEDIFF to be since the beginning of time, till yesterday, and if TIME_STAMP is greater, then its within 24 hours. But it is still showing all dates, not within 24 hours.

Comment: I added "* 1000" in the where-statement, based on the value in the select-statement, your time_stamp column seems not to be seconds since 1970, but milliseconds.

Comment: when I add * 1000 at the end of TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(... it gives error "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."

Comment: Ah, of course, 1000 needs to be a bigint as well, updated again :)